# Why isn't Windows Firewall Defender working on my Internet Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, firewall, internet-explorer, opera, windows-firewall

I tried blocking my Internet Explorer's INBOUND and OUTBOUND connection with Windows Firewall Defender:

[Image of firewall placed on Internet Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmCyQ.png)

However I still can use Internet Explorer even with all the rules set, and I even went out of my way to block all `.exe` files inside the folder, not just the `iexplorer.exe` file. On the contrary, when I blocked all the `.exe` files for the Opera browser, that did in fact stop the access to the internet:

[Image of firewall placed on Opera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb9nq.png)

**Question:**
Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Comment: Why not simply REMOVE the internet explorer?  It's pointless to have it if you are going to block it.  In windows 10, it can be removed via "Optional Features".

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I can't agree with you more, but I was using it now just for the purpose of testing whether or not the firewall works properly. As much as I agree with you that IE is not useful, me knowing why the firewall isn't working is the question at hand.

Comment: Do you have a 64-bit operating system?

Comment: You probably have to block some DLL used by IE.

Comment: [See this](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/block-windows-internet-explorer-accessing-internet/) .. I am guessing that is what @Daniel_B is eluding to with his 64 bit question.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that the 64bit version of Windows 10 contains the Internet Explorer two times, one time as 32bit and one time as 64bit executable:

```
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
```

The interesting part is that both executables are often used at the same time. Even if you start the 64bit version by default internally it spawns the 32bit version. You can see this nicely using e.g. Sysinternals Process Explorer.

Hence if you add a blocking outbound rule for both Internet Explorere executables mentioned above IE is totally blocked. I just tested that on my system Windows 10 v2004.