# Old version Adobe Acrobat Reader crashes after 10-15 seconds

Tags: windows-7, windows-firewall, adobe-reader

I have an old version of Adobe Acrobat Reader and do not want to update.
However, when I open a pdf with the program, after 10 or so seconds, the program crashes (independent of which pdf is opened). This does not happen when my computer is not connected to the internet.

I've tried adding Windows Defender FW rules blocking all inbound and outbound traffic associated with all .exe files in my `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe` directory. But that still doesn't work.

The only thing that works is blocking all outbound traffic that does not correspond to a rule.

How does Reader manage to contact the internet while all its exe's are blocked by firewall?

Question related to this one: [Why isn't Windows Firewall Defender working on my Internet Explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1563303/why-isnt-windows-firewall-defender-working-on-my-internet-explorer)

Comment: What version?  Adobe ends support of old versions as a security risk just as is Windows 7.  You do need to upgrade.

Comment: Why use Adobe, if it crashes? There are a slew of free, faster, safer, more efficient and more versatile and stable readers, such as Sumatra PDF (https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/downloadafter, lightweight and fast) and PDF-XChange Editor (https://www.tracker-software.com/product/downloads, larger but able to edit PDF).

Comment: Modern Adobe works fine. It is only crashing because it is old and outdated.  I do not disagree with you at all, just noting that Adobe Reader does work fine.

Comment: @John, agreed. My comment was meant particularly for the old Win 7 machine (itself unsafe), that might need 32-bit software.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using Firewall logging I figured out something was contacting an IP address in range 104.117.77.96/29 right when the program crashed.

**Solution 1**: block the IP address range 104.117.77.96/29 with a Firewall outbound rule.

**Solution 2**: Using the following commands in PowerShell:

```
auditpol /set /subcategory:"{0CCE9226-69AE-11D9-BED3-505054503030}" /success:enable /failure:enable
Get-EventLog security -newest 100 -InstanceId 5156 -Message *104.117.77.9* | select Message -first 1 | Format-List -Force
```

It is seen that the application responsible is `C:\Program files (x86)\trend micro\officescan client\tmproxy.exe`, so I just disabled outbound traffic for all exe's in `trend micro` using this handy .bat script:

```
@ setlocal enableextensions 
@ cd /d "%~dp0"

for /R %%f in (*.exe) do (
  netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Blocked: %%f" dir=out program="%%f" action=block
)
pause
```

Comment: It's unclear why disabling trend micro programs stopped Reader from crashing and what is the connection between the two. Also missing is what effect did this have on the installed trend micro software in general.

Comment: It's basically a bloatware feature of Adobe to check for latest version and refuse to continue to run if not.